# convert short[] to ushort[]

Tags: c#, casting, short, ushort

I need to convert short[] to ushort[] in C#

```
public ushort[] Pixels16bits;

 GrayscalePixelDataS16 Pixeldata = PixelDataFactory.Create(img.PixelData, 0) as GrayscalePixelDataS16; //Pixeldata has short[] values

Pixels16bits = pixeldata; //Here's where I struggle, I need to convert to ushort prior to assign to pixels16bits
```

Thanks

Comment: Fun trick: `short[] signed = new short[1]; ushort[] unsigned = (ushort[])(object)signed;` works but doesn't actually convert (i.e. `unsigned.GetType()` returns `short[]`). This does not produce an exception at runtime. The intermediate `object` step is required because the C# spec does not allow this cast, but the CLR spec does.

Comment: @CodesInChaos But it *doesn't* work.  It *compiles*.  That doesn't make it a solution.  Array covariance is specific to reference types.

Comment: @Servy It compiles and doesn't throw a runtime error. `short` to `ushort` is representation preserving, so the runtime allows it. It works in the sense that you get an object that can be treated as the result type in almost every situation, despite the runtime type remaining the original type. This isn't array covariance, but a very similar mechanism.

Comment: This question is about converting arrays `short[]` to `ushort[]`, the supposed duplicate is about converting integral values `short` to `ushort`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a couple options:

```
img.PixelData.Cast<ushort>().ToArray();
```

Or perhaps:

```
img.PixelData.Select(Convert.ToUInt16).ToArray();
```

Both take advantage of LINQs ability to apply a transform function to a collection.

Comment: Your second variant can be simplified by using a method group conversion instead of a lambda: `.Select(Convert.ToUInt16)`

Comment: excellent! this did the trick: `Pixels16bits=Pixeldata.Data.Select(Convert.ToUInt16).ToArray();`

Answer (score 2):

As normal solution I recommend:

```
unsigned = ConvertAll(signed, i => (ushort)i)
```

This produces less garbage than LINQ solutions while being similarly concise and readable.

A good old fashioned loop is also a consideration, since it allows you to convert into an existing array, instead of allocating a new one.

As the value conversion function you can either use:

- The C style cast `i => (ushort)i` which does not complain about integer overflow by default (you can change that in the compiler settings)

  To be really explicit you could write `i => unchecked((ushort)i)` or `i => checked((ushort)i)` depending on which behaviour you want.
- `Convert.ToInt16` which throws an `OverflowException` if the input is larger that `short.MaxValue` regardless of the compiler settings.

---

There is a fun/evil trick that allows you to treat a `short[]` as a `ushort[]` without actually converting:

```
short[] signed = new short[]{-1};
signed.GetType().Dump();// short[]

ushort[] unsigned = (ushort[])(object)signed;

unsigned.GetType().Dump();// still short[]
unsigned[0].Dump(); // 65535
```

It compiles and doesn't throw a runtime error.

The CLR specification says that `ushort[]` and `short[]` are compatible, since converting `short` to `ushort` preserves the representation. This is a similar mechanism to array covariance.

The C# spec on the other hand does not allow this conversion. That's why the intermediate conversion to `object` is necessary.

Comment: I love the trick you gave about the casting via object